# Reorder a Python List

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following list: first is some servername, second the name of a virtual machine on this server, the tuples have in real some more entries :

```
("servername", "VmName", "vmsize", "vmdisks" ....)

ListToSort = [
("server1", "VMblax"),
("server1","bigmachine"),
("server1", "somemachinename"), 
("server2","VMothername"),
("server2", "nextmachine"), 
("serverxy", "reallybigmachine"), 
("server4", "vm7"), 
("serverxx", "somename")]
```

I want to reorder this List to a List like this:

```
SortedList = [
("server1", "VMblax"),
("server2", "VMothername"),
("serverxy", "reallybigmachine"),
("server4", "vm7"),
("serverxx", "somename"),
("server1", "bigmachine"),
("server2", "nextmachine"),
("server1", "somemachine")]
```

[(**first** tuple of **first** unique servername),(**first** tuple of **second** unique servername),(**first** tuple of **third** unique servername),(**second** tuple of **first** unique servername), (**second** tuple of **second** unique servername), (**third** tuple of **first** unique servername),

All **first** of unique Servernames, then all **second** tuples of unique server names, then all **third** and so on..

I created a List of the Unique first servername.

Like

```
("server1", "server2", "serverxy", "server4", "serverxx")

uniqueServerList = []
serverListe = [i[0] for i in ListToSort] # get all first Tuples Values
```

For server in serverList:

```
    if server not in uniqueServerList:
        uniqueServerList.append(server)
```

but from here I could not find a solution to built the sorted list..

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: The "sorted list" appears to be in a random order to me.  Can you clarify the pattern that you want?

Comment: its not random.. it should list up the first entry from the first server here: server1, then the first entry from the next server, here server2 , then the first entry from the next server,, after that the second entry from the first server, second entry from the second server ,,after that third entry from first server (if it has)..third entry from second server...and so on..  thx for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping the tuples first by server and then merging them again:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

def sort_server_tuples(server_tuples):
    grouped_list = OrderedDict()
    for server, vmname in sorted(server_tuples):
        if server not in grouped_list:
            grouped_list[server] = []
        grouped_list[server].append((server, vmname))

    return [t for t in chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(*grouped_list.values())) if t]
```

Comment: First i want to thank you for your fast response! I tried it but i get a NameError: name 'chain' is not defined

Comment: realy great voodoo here for me ! great it is working! Big thanks to you!

Comment: I’ve added the chain import to the answer as well. ;-)